# Click submit button multiple times using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yui

I want that my jquery code click multiple times in a submit button inside the following form.

I have a YUI event listener tracking the submit event and It calls a Callback function each time. How can I click once and generate multiple submit events ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

 button { margin:10px; }
 div { color:blue; font-weight:bold; }
 span { color:red; }
 </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form class="forms" id="result_form" method="post" >
 <input type="submit" id = "click" value="Sum Result" ></input>
 </form>

 <button id = "B2">Button #2</button>

  <script>

  $("#click").click(function () {
  alert("Test");
  });

  $("#B2").click(function () {
  for(j=0;j<10;j++)
  $("#click").trigger('click');


   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

In the code above when I click on B2 I just get one alert but when I put the submit outside the form I can get the 10 alerts.

Comment: You want to call multiple times the submit button because you want to submit a form multiple times?

Comment: Yes. I want to submit it multiples times clicking only once sending an action. like  this

     <form class="forms" id="result_form" method="post" action="cmd/result">
       <input type="submit" value="Sum Result" disabled="true">                              </input>
</form>

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting a form. The effect is that you leave the page, and so you stop all your scripts. As you didn't precise the `action` parameter of the form, it's the current page, so you're simply replacing the current page by itself at the first iteration of your loop.

If you want to make more than one request from one page without reloading, the usual solution is to use ajax.

You could for example do

```
for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
  $.ajax('someurl');
```

Comment: But you can't submit a form more than once, so you have to find another solution. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Is it possible to generate n times HTTP POST by clicking only once in the submit button in the form instead of clicking n times ?. My YUI event listener will then generate n POST  

YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST','/cmd/resultxhr'+arr2, webserver.result_callback);

Answer (score 0):

You can POST the form without reloading the page using Ajax. In order to do that you need to first stop the default behavior of the browser when submitting the form. You do that by calling `e.preventDefault()` on the submit event. Then you use ajax and serialize the form into data. Both jQuery and YUI provide utilities for doing that:

```
// jQuery
$('#result_form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post('cmd/result', $(this).serialize());
});

// YUI
Y.one('#result_form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Y.io('cmd/result', {
    method: 'POST',
    form: { id: this }
  });
});
```